# reCaptcha data-callback only gets called once? (AngularJS SPA)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I know the title sounds kind of redundant, but let me elaborate. I am making an SPA website using AngularJS, and I'm trying to add reCaptcha to the email form on the contact page. Right now, this works:

*Only if the contact page is accessed directly (and not by navigating from the homepage)

*Only once per session. After submitting the form, the only way to get the captcha data-callback to work after clicking is to reload the page.

I've done a fair bit of research but so far I haven't found any answers. Here's the html form:

```
<form ng-submit="check_recaptcha($event)" action="mailer.php" method="POST" id="email-form" 
      style="text-align: left; color: black; font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;">
        <recaptcha required class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=". . ."
        data-callback="recaptcha_completed" data-expired-callback="recaptcha_expired"></recaptcha>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" 
        style="margin-top: 20px;">Send</button>

      </form>
```

And here is my angular controller for the contact page:

```
danApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope, orderService) {
  $scope.state = 'contact';
  console.log(orderService.getMessage());

  $scope.message = orderService.getMessage();
  orderService.setMessage("");

  //this variable will tell whether or not to allow the form submission. The only
  //way to set it to true is to fill out the recaptcha
  $scope.allow_form_submission = false;

  //this variable detects a bad attempt (recaptcha not filled out). Its used to 
  //display the red text when this happens
  $scope.bad_attempt = false;

  //recaptcha callback, gets run when the recaptcha is successfully completed
  var recaptcha_completed = function () {
    console.log("recaptcha completed");
    $scope.allow_form_submission = true;
  }

  //recaptcha callback, gets run when recaptcha submission expires
  var recaptcha_expired = function () {
    console.log("recaptcha expired");
    $scope.allow_form_submission = false;
  }

  //We need to set this variable to the window so that it can be accessed by recaptcha
  //outside of angularJS
  window.recaptcha_completed = recaptcha_completed;
  window.recaptcha_expired = recaptcha_expired;

  //checks to see if the recaptcha has been filled out or not. used as the form 
  //submission callback (ng-submit)
  $scope.check_recaptcha = function (e) {
    if (!$scope.allow_form_submission) {
      //alert("Please fill in the recaptcha");
      $scope.bad_attempt = true;
      e.preventDefault();

      //this allows the form to be filled out again
      $("#email-form").unbind('click');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

And here is the recaptcha directive definition:

```
danApp.directive('recaptcha', ['$window', '$compile', function($window, $compile) {
return {
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        var key = '. . .';
        activate();
        function activate() {
            if(angular.isDefined($window.grecaptcha)) {
                $window.grecaptcha.render(elem[0], {
                    'sitekey': key
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("didn't work. . .");
            }
        }
    }
}}]);
```

I know this is alot but is there anybody who can figure out where this issue stems from?

Comment: You are creating global handlers that are closed over view instance state. That is likely wrong. Actually, the context is hard to see since the enclosing function is not shown.

Comment: You have mentioned WHEN the code works. But its not clear when the code doesn't work WHAT happens? Does it give you any error? `check_recaptcha` isn't called? Also what are you trying by executing `$("#email-form").unbind('click');`?

Comment: sorry, I guess I was unclear. The problem is that the recaptcha_completed() function won't get called if the user has used the recaptcha once already. They need to reload the page. (This is a problem because if you desire to fill out the form twice, it won't work unless you reload). And the $("#email-form").unbind('click'); is to allow the form to be submitted again. When you call e.preventDefault(), the form can't be submitted unless you add that code.